# Sort an array according to the sequence of another array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an Array `A[]={8, 9, 11, 14, 16, 20};` which I have to sort according to another array `B[]={6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3};`.

Sorted `A` would be `A[]={20, 16, 8, 9, 14, 11};`

So, How `A` will be sorted is told in `B`. 
First element of `B` is the greatest so first element of `A` will also be the greatest. Third element of `B` is smallest so third element of `A` will also be the smallest

If `B` were something sorted Descending like `{100, 84, 74, 51, 5, 1}` Then `A` will also be sorted Descending.
Examples:
1. if `B = {12, 8, 14, 156, 2, 84}`, `A` would be `{11, 9, 14, 20, 8, 16}`
2. if `B = {2, 3, 45, 0, 7, 56}`, `A` would be `{9, 11, 16, 8, 14, 20}`

Its like if I have some friends of different ages, and I want to give them something according to their ages. Eldest person will get the biggest one... smaller than him will get the smaller one than that.. and so on.

I have seen similar questions but they are not like my problem.
 My idea is to sort both first. And then rearrange.

Is there any fast solution?

Comment: Exactly this question has been here a few days, maybe a week, ago.
Except for your array literals don't give a hint how exactly `B` specifies the sorting order of `A`. Check them please.

Comment: I have no idea how `B` determines the order of `A`, please clarify your sorting criteria.

Comment: A 6 in B means the sixth element of A should be where the 6 is located. The 6 is at the beginning, so the sixth element of A should move to the beginning.

Comment: Is values in ur array B are actually showing indexes to sort array A ? If so than it is very simple you just have to swap ur array members based on values and index of array B.

Comment: first element of B is the greatest.. so first element of A will also be the greatest, third element of B is the smallest so third element of A will also be the smallest....

Comment: another example... if B[]={102, 94, 4, 17, 87, 54} then the sorted A will also be the same.. Sorry I didn't give much example first time..

Comment: @SymonSaroar, this is not called "sorting". It is called "permuting". Not a common word outside of CS, but it is the proper word for what you want. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: There are *many* solutions which can quickly be found through Google, once you know the proper words to use. Here's one: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reorder-a-array-according-to-given-indexes/

Comment: @AlexD Its not like that, please re consider your opinion.

Comment: Though its permuting .. but its not like that GeekForGeeks article..

Comment: @SymonSaroar, I am sorry. Your second example shows that what you want *is* sorting, *not* permutation. Your first example "tricked" me. Sorry about this. I'll post an answer for you right now.

Comment: Please "rollback" my edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate the inverse of the sorted permutation of `B`, and then order sorted `A` in that order.  You can do this pretty easily with the standard library.

```
int A[] = { 8,  9, 11, 14, 16, 20};
int B[] = { 6,  5,  1,  2,  4,  3};

const auto ASIZE = std::extent<decltype(A)>::value;
const auto BSIZE = std::extent<decltype(B)>::value;

// A and B must be the same size
assert(ASIZE == BSIZE);

// p = sorted permutation of B largest to smallest
std::vector<size_t> p(ASIZE);
std::iota(p.begin(), p.end(), 0);
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), [&](size_t i1, size_t i2) { return B[i1] > B[i2]; });

// pinv = inverse of p
std::vector<size_t> pinv(ASIZE);
for (size_t i = 0; i < ASIZE; ++i)
    pinv[p[i]] = i;

// Sort A largest to smallest
std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A), [&](int v1, int v2) { return v1 > v2; });
```

Then you can indirect through `pinv` to get `A` in the order you want.

```
for (size_t index : pinv)
    std::cout << A[index] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
// Output is: 20 16 8 9 14 11
```

Answer (score 4):

From your first example, it appeared that you wanted to permute `A` using an array of indices `B`. But the second example shows that you actually do want a sort, but with comparisons based on the values in `B` rather than those in `A`.

So what you need is a sort function which takes a "sort key function". The sort key function should be passed an array index as an argument.

C's `qsort` does take a key function, but the arguments to the key function are the *values being compared*, not the *indices of the values being compared*. So it won't work for you.

You'll probably have to write your own sort function. It's not hard. If the arrays are small, a simple insertion sort will do just fine:

```
void sort_by_keys(int *values, int *sortkeys, int size)
{
   int i, j;

   for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
     j = i;

     /* For a usual insertion sort, the condition here
      * would be values[j] < values[j-1]. */
     while (j > 0 && sortkeys[j] < sortkeys[j-1]) {
       swap(values, j, j - 1);
       swap(sortkeys, j, j - 1);
       j--;
     }
   }
}
```

(You'll have to write your own `swap`.)

If the arrays are larger, you can code yourself up a recursive or iterative quicksort. It's not hard either. Make sure you also write some test cases to ensure it works. Your test cases should include empty arrays and arrays with 1 item.

Comment: Shell sort shares this simplicity while being much more efficient - which makes it more recommended for this problem.

Comment: @plasmacel, if I wanted to be pedantic, I would say that it depends on the size of the arrays. (Insertion sort is very hard to beat on small arrays.) But it's not worth debating. Shell sort would also be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a copy operation and not a sort.

The second array shows the *ordering* of the elements of the first array.  The difference is to subtract 1 from the second array to get the offset of the sorted array.

```
const int original_array[]={8, 9, 11, 14, 16, 20};
const int ordering_array[]={6, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3};
int result array[6];
for (unsigned int i = 0;  
     i < sizeof(original_array)/sizeof(original_array[0]);
     ++i)
{
  int source_index = ordering_array[i] - 1;
  result_array[i] = original_array[source_index];
}
```

Comment: Well, B can also be like this `B={102, 94, 4, 17, 87, 54}`